# Hilbert Spaces from Dagger Categories

Tags: category-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, monoidal-categories, dagger-categories

Dagger compact closed categories are commonly said to be an abstraction of Hilbert spaces and is suppose to capture concepts such as unitary maps, scalars, basis, inner products. See for example the below Wikipedia article and the introduction in the paper by Peter Selinger.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_compact_category

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/SelingerPositiveMaps.pdf

In particular, let $\mathcal{C}$ be a dagger compact closed category with tensor unit $I$. Let $A$ be another object in $\mathcal{C}$. Then we can consider morphisms in $\textrm{Hom}(I, A)$ to be the vectors in the "Hilbert space". If $v,w \in \textrm{Hom}(I,A)$ then we can define the "inner-product" as:
$$\langle v, w \rangle_{\mathcal{C}} = v^{\dagger}w.$$
In the case of $\mathcal{C} = \textrm{Hilb}$ this construction returns back the original Hilbert space and inner-product. However, of course, in general this does not give a Hilbert space as a priori $\textrm{Hom}(I,A)$ is not even a vector space and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\mathcal{C}}$ is not a true inner-product.

Now this is my question.

> For a dagger compact closed category $\mathcal{C}$ (possibly requiring further restrictions on $\mathcal{C}$), does there exist a general procedure to build a [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) using the data of $(\textrm{Hom}(I,A), \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\mathcal{C}})$ ? Or more generally, is there a way to obtain a collection of Hilbert spaces from $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: you may also be interested in: https://www.pnas.org/doi/full/10.1073/pnas.2117024119

Comment: @ac15 Thank you for the reference. If I understood the paper correctly, under additional assumptions, it shows that a monoidal dagger category $(\mathcal{C}, \boxtimes)$ is equivalent to $\textrm{Hilb}$ (I assume they really mean equivalent to a sub-category of $\textrm{Hilb}$?). In particular, is Theorem $10$ saying that there is a monoidal dagger equivalence between $(\mathcal{C}, \boxtimes)$ and $(\textrm{Hilb}, \otimes)$ where $\otimes$ is the classical tensor product between Hilbert spaces? (I apologise in advance if I have misunderstood it as my background is not in category theory.)

Comment: (cont.)  If so, that is perhaps too strong for what I am looking for. I was hoping that the tensor product structure in $\mathcal{C}$ will not give rise to the classical tensor product on $\textrm{Hilb}$ so that it will give a different way to "combine" Hilbert spaces.

Comment: (cont.) It seems like in this case you don't gain anything by working in $(\mathcal{C}, \boxtimes)$ as it same as working in the classical category $(\textrm{Hilb}, \otimes)$. Though, please correct me if I have said anything wrong.